# Migration from SQL Server 2008 to 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

An organization wants to shift back from 2008 to 2005: I can't influence this.

What would be the most significant problems based on your experience that I could face?

I have noticed that the data type `Date` is going to affect the shift back.

Comment: Any of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.100%29.aspx.

Comment: I hope *they* are aware that even the *extended support* for SQL Server 2005 will **end in April 2016** - no more security patches after that! Seems rather risky business to me .....